# Interpretation of Equation of energy stored in continuous charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, work, potential-energy

In the book *"Introduction to Electrodynamics"* by David J. Griffiths, **$\boldsymbol\S$ 2.4.3$\blacksquare $ The Energy of a Continuous Charge Distribution**,  I came across this equation for total energy stored in a continuous charge distribution:

$$
W = \frac{1}{2}\int_\text{all space} \rho V d\tau
\tag{2.43}\label{2.43}
$$

using integration by parts this equation is derived from it:
$$
W = \frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2} \left( \int_{V} E^2 d\tau + \int_{S} V\vec{E} \cdot da \right)
\tag{2.44}\label{2.44}
$$

but I have difficulty to get an intuition of the second equation. what does integrating $E^2$ over volume mean ? and what does $VE$ mean ? is there a good interpretation of those terms ? or should I treat them purely as mathematical expressions and move on without seeking intuition?

Note: I am familiar with concept of integration of a function over a volume. Also I know how the second equation is derived from the first one mathematically. I just want to make an intuition of why the terms $E^2$ and $V\vec{E}$ ? for example if we simplify the equation by integrating over all space we would have:

$$
W = \frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2}  \int_{\text{all space}} E^2 d\tau
$$
My question is why integrating $E^2$ over all space should give us energy of the system ? and if we are integrating $E^2$ on a limited volume, why $\frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2}  \int_{S} V\vec{E} \cdot da$ would be responsible for the remaining energy ?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458987/

Comment: *What does integrating $E^2$ over volume mean?* Are you confused about what the integral of a function over a volume means, or are you confused about what $E^2$ is?

Comment: *What does $VE$ mean?* It should be $V\vec E$. It means the scalar function $V$ multiplied by the vector function $\vec E$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Energy of continious charge distribution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458987/). Also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610960/226902